# Change background color (of entire view) on button click in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using iOS/Xamarin

When the user clicks a button, I'd like to change the background color of my view controller's main view (View).

In the button click event, I tried this:

```
partial void MyButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        SetBackgroundColor(View);
    });
}
```

but it doesn't work. I tried a few other main thread/uithread things but no luck.

If I call `SetBackgroundColor(View)` from the `ViewDidLoad` of course it works. I suspect this is a UI thread issue.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BackgroundColor` property on the `UIViewController's` `View` property.

```
partial void MyButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
}
```

Comment: that's what my function is doing (SetBackgroundColor).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the above code is good - somewhere else in the code someone was setting another layer on top of the background so I never saw it =/